# Pandas: apply result_type="expand": wrong dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, apply, dtype

I want to add multiple columns to a DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        (0, 1),
        (1, 1),
        (1, 2),
    ],
    columns=['a', 'b']
)


def apply_fn(row) -> (int, float):
    return int(row.a + row.b), float(row.a / row.b)


df[['c', 'd']] = df.apply(apply_fn, result_type='expand', axis=1)
```

Result:

```
>>> df
   a  b    c    d
0  0  1  1.0  0.0
1  1  1  2.0  1.0
2  1  2  3.0  0.5
```

```py
>>> df.dtypes
a      int64
b      int64
c    float64
d    float64
dtype: object
```

Why is column `c` not of dtype `int`? Can I specify this somehow? Something like `.apply(..., dtypes=[int, float])`?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using apply in this way, and not a vectorized option?

Comment: you mean why not `df['c'] =  df['a'] + df['b']`? yes, there is a good reason. this is just a toy example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is happening because `result_type='expand'` causes to be expanded as a Series, so the first **row** is in its own series, then the next row, etc. *But*, because Series objects can only have one dtype, the ints get converted to floats.

For example, look at this:

```
>>> pd.Series([1, 0.0])
0    1.0
1    0.0
dtype: float64
```

One workaround would be to call `tolist` on the `apply` call, and wrap it in a call to `DataFrame`:

```
>>> df[['c', 'd']] = pd.DataFrame(df.apply(apply_fn, axis=1).tolist())
   a  b  c    d
0  0  1  1  0.0
1  1  1  2  1.0
2  1  2  3  0.5
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I assume the performance is not great, though? I need to apply quickly on a big DataFrame.

Comment: I'm not really sure. I'd assume the performance would be close to your original code, which might be slow just by merit of using `apply`...

Comment: Yes. I will end up using numpy and Cython, I guess...

Answer (score 2):

You can chain with `astype`

```
df.apply(apply_fn, axis=1, result_type='expand').astype({0:'int', 1:'float'})
Out[147]: 
   0    1
0  1  0.0
1  2  1.0
2  3  0.5
```

Comment: Thanks! But this is about 2x slower than the .tolist() answer.